# Bounds on the line for entire functions of exponential type

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function on the complex plane $\mathbb C$, assume that $$|f(z)|\le e^{|z|}.$$ Does the property $$|f(x)|\le e^{-|x|}, \qquad x\in\mathbb R,$$ imply $f\equiv 0$?

More generally, characterize the class of majorants $w$ on the real line, for which $|f(x)|\le w(x)$ yields $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: You could find interesting http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol22/domar.pdf

Comment: If $|f(x)|\le e^{-|x|}, x\in\mathbb R,$ then $|f(x)|\le 1, x\in\mathbb R.$ Then it follows from http://www.mscand.dk/article/download/10453/8474 that $|f(x+iy)|\le e^{a|y|}$ for some $a.$ Thus, the conditions in http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol22/domar.pdf are as general as possible, once we assume some bound on the real axis.

Comment: I don't know if the answer is yes. $k(x)=-|x|$ doesn't satisfy any of the hypothesis on the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate on the real line implies that $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$. Thus, $f$ belongs to the Paley-Wiener space $PW_1$, which is the Fourier-image of $L^2(-1, 1)$. Therefore, the function $e^{iz}f$ belongs to the Hardy class $H^2$ in the upper half-plane $\mathbb C_+$, which is the Fourier image of $L^2(0, +\infty)$. If $f\not\equiv 0$, this yields the condition $$\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{|\log |f(x)||\,dx}{1+x^2}<\infty.$$ By the assumption, $\log |f(x)|\le -|x|$, which contradicts the preceding formula. Hence $f\equiv 0$.

This argument works if $w\in L^2$, $w\le 1$, and $\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\log\frac{1}{w(x)}\, dx}{1+x^2}=\infty$.